# How to make a drop-down, "while-editing-cell" list in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, function

In Excel, as everyone knows, when you type "=" and follow with "S" - a drop-list of functions occures:

- SUM
- SUMIF
- SUMIFS
- SUBTOTAL
- SWITCH, etc.

And if you continue typing with "UM" - only theese options will left:

- SUM
- SUMIF
- SUMIFS

My question, is there any possible way (via VBA, or else) to set similar drop-list to **another** symbol, like brackets (")? So when you type brackets (") *while editing a cell*, a list with some options would occure and so its shrinks as you type some letters (and whole set of its options is set as simple range somewhere in a sheet - *like it used to be in "data validation"*). And I want such list to occure **everytime** I use brackets while editing a cell. How can I do that?

Comment: Your biggest issue here is that macros do not run while you're in cell edit mode.  You'd need to do something like use an ActiveX textbox to capture your keystrokes and then populate a listbox with possible matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like Data validation.
So for example you have Shoe Colour.
You create an area on spreadsheet
with values sorted values, and create a named range (to left of formula), where up down triangle is. To do that select the cells with the values, then enter **Colour** into the range, being sure to hit return/enter.
[image: Typing 'Colour' into range and pressing ENTER]

Black
Blue
Brown
Maroon
In another cell where you want to select a colour from the list, make a cell active by selecting it (A1 in my case).

Select the Data ribbon tab, then Data validation icon.
[image: Select Data Validation from Data Ribbon tab]

Then in the settings select List from the drop down, and in the source place the formula **=Colour** You can make optional by checking allow-blank.
[image: Fill in the Data Validation Settings]

Then you have a drop down list to select from:
[image]

There are types other than 'list' too:

[image: Data validation type]

and you can do things like have messages. Have a play around with the other tabs in the Data Validation pane.