# How can i add a validation rule in excel file to prevent user from entering "abc="?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I want to apply a validation rule in excel file to prevent user from entering the text **"abc="**. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent anything with formulas. A formula can always be deleted. With VBA you can prevent stuff, but we need more details to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your validation rule:

```
=ISERR(SEARCH("*abc=*",A1))
```

Comment: Will it prevent the following
www.google.com/indi----abc=---123cgx

Comment: Hey it works but for cell A1 only, how can i apply this for the whole excel workbook?

Comment: @GauravSetia You can `copy/paste` the format to the cells you want.  You could go to `Manage Rules` and change the `Applies to` parameter (be sure to use absolute addressing mode here.

Comment: can you please guide me through the step by step procedure of applying this rule to whole excel sheet. I tried but was unable to do so.

Comment: @GauravSetia One way:  select `A1`.  Then select the entire worksheet (click the box above the row numbers and to the left of the column headers). (`A1` should still be the active cell).  Then go to Data Validation and enter the formula as you did initially.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom 'Validation criteria' . For cell A1, the formula should look like:

```
=IF(A1="abc=",FALSE,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found solution to this. Use Data Validation. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45117419/495157).