# Excel lookup with two input values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

I have a database of multiple tables and am trying to design an equation in Excel that will return the height of a given toy from a specific manufacturer. What is the best way to go about using two inputs? i have tried working with VLOOKUP() but was unable to tailor it to my needs. I also tried nested IF statements which greatly complicated my equation and will only work with small amounts of data. Is this possible to do in Excel and if so how? The equation in the image below has dropdown selectors which aren't displayed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that I'm giving here will require that you rearrange your data tables a little bit, but has the benefit that it can be easily extended later on to deal with any additional data and additional lookup conditions.

Steps:

1. Move all your data tables into one single contiguous table, and add one additional column for 'Toy type' (as shown below).
2. Enter the formula as shown below into a cell, but without the outer braces. Then then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter (this tells Excel that the formula is an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) and results in the braces being added).

[image: excel snapshot]

The lookup formula in this case is made up from an [`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) and [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function. This combination allows you to define multiple lookup-criteria. How this works exactly is explained in more detail [here](http://www.exceltactics.com/vlookup-multiple-criteria-using-index-match/) and [here](http://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/).

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like you've got two lookup tables... So depending on the Toy Type cell, you'd lookup vlookup area1 or area2.
See [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mDwjdZ5WLucFmMTvRvIh0DwHDlMpIKL22Fa4Pt65GkU/edit#gid=0)
**Results**
[image: Results]
**Formula**
[image: Formula]
You might like to make cell B8 a drop down list too if you were to use my layout in Excel rather than Googledocs. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116426/how-to-make-a-drop-down-while-editing-cell-list-in-excel/45117419#45117419)

Comment: I don't know... Some people are so impatient...  Got -ve vote in space of couple of minutes, when I said I'd post back a Googledocs sample...

Comment: Is your Data in the same sheet and the result also?

Comment: Yes. Click first 'here' above Results, that's where I got screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lookup based on the Toy Type to choose the range for your other lookups.

I made a table with ToyType and CellRange.  Assuming your Dolls table started at B2 you would have ToyType = Dolls and CellRange = C3:D9 etc.

Then make a lookup using `=VLOOKUP(SelectedToyType, NewTableRange, CellRangeColumn, FALSE)`

Finally in your Toy Height lookup it would be `=VLOOKUP(SelectedToyHeight, INDIRECT(FirstLookup),2,FALSE)`

This will let you keep the same basic table structure, and be able to add more toy types / adjust the lookup ranges in the future.